# SQL -Single quote values pass to where IN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two table,
Exapmle table A - with data

```
A
ID  value
1   aa@test.com,bb@test.com

B
ID  Email
1   aa@test.com
2   bb@test.com
3   cc@test.com
```

I need records from table B where its match with Table A

```
Select * from B where Email IN (select * from A where ID=1)
```

I don’t want to use dynamic query.
I have tried this -

```
Select * from B where Email IN (select REPLACE(stuff((select ',' + ''''+ 
cast(value as varchar(max)) + '''' from A where ID=1  
for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''),',',''','''))
```

But its not showing any result.

Please help me.

Comment: One of the first things you *should* learn in database modelling is that the correct way to store multiple values of the same "type" is to use multiple *rows*. Your first table doesn't do this so it'll cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix your data structure.  One simplistic method uses `like`:

```
select b.*
from b
where exists (select 1
              from a
              where ',' + a.email + ',' like '%,' + b.email + ',%';
```

Performance will be awful, but that is the price you pay for a really bad data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Select *
      from B 
       inner join A on ',' + A.email + ',' like '%,' + B.email + ',%';
```